# Can not find mi_fifo.so and mi_rpc.so files while install Kamailio on Sierra

Tags: macos, sip, pjsip, kamailio

I try to start kamailio on Sierra OS. When I run kamailio with "/usr/local/sbin/kamailio -c" I get this error:

```
 0(49276) ERROR: <core> [core/sr_module.c:571]: load_module(): could not find module <mi_fifo> in </usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules/>
 0(49276) CRITICAL: <core> [core/cfg.y:3401]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 219, column 12-23: failed to load module
 0(49276) ERROR: <core> [core/sr_module.c:571]: load_module(): could not find module <mi_rpc> in </usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules/>
 0(49276) CRITICAL: <core> [core/cfg.y:3401]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 236, column 12-22: failed to load module
 0(49276) ERROR: <core> [core/modparam.c:152]: set_mod_param_regex(): No module matching <mi_fifo> found
 0(49276) CRITICAL: <core> [core/cfg.y:3404]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 290, column 54: Can't set module parameter
ERROR: bad config file (3 errors)
 0(49276) INFO: <core> [core/sctp_core.c:53]: sctp_core_destroy(): SCTP API not initialized
```

When I open /usr/local/lib64/kamailio/modules/ there are no mi_fifo.so and no mi_rpc.so files. Where can I get these files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are running Kamailio v5.0.x. Starting with v5.0.0, the Management Interface (MI) was removed, being marked as deprecated for several years. With it, all modules prefixed with **mi_** have been removed.

The RPC Interface has to be used now. To get the equivalent of FIFO or Datagram Socket for controlling Kamailio, you have to use **jsonrpcs** module.

In short, remove the lines related to loading mi_fifo and mi_rpc (respectively loadmodule and modparam lines) and load jsronrpcs.

More details about what needs to be done when upgrading from Kamailio v4.4 to v5.0 are listed at:

- https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/install/upgrade/4.4.x-to-5.0.0

Comment: Thank u for your comment) I have already guessed about it and I installed Kamailio 4.4